# Axis2 Client ADBException

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm having a problem with my classes created during a WSDL import. I point to a remote WSDL that was built using (version 1.7.3). I am also using axis2 locally (version 1.7.3). When I generate my stub for the WSDL everything seems to work fine but when calling a function that requires no parameters I am receiving the error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://common.ad/xsd}classForLoggerString
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at ad.ecs.systemdictionary.script.ScriptServiceStub.fromOM(ScriptServiceStub.java)
at ad.ecs.systemdictionary.script.ScriptServiceStub.getServiceInfo(ScriptServiceStub.java:7888)
at ad.ecs.systemdictionary.script.ScriptAccess.getServiceInfo(ScriptAccess.java:702)
at ad.ecs.core.scriptengine.Script.testFunction(Script.java:24)
at ad.ecs.rest.DrugNames.getDrugNames(DrugNames.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://common.ad/xsd}classForLoggerString
at ad.ecs.systemdictionary.script.ScriptServiceStub$ServiceInfo$Factory.parse(ScriptServiceStub.java:34966)
at ad.ecs.systemdictionary.script.ScriptServiceStub$GetServiceInfoResponse$Factory.parse(ScriptServiceStub.java:16211)
... 52 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://common.ad/xsd}classForLoggerString
at ad.ecs.systemdictionary.script.ScriptServiceStub$ServiceInfo$Factory.parse(ScriptServiceStub.java:34960)
... 53 more
```

In my searching I've mainly found people who attritbuted this problem to their parameters, yet my function doesn't have any.